# Render MVC views inside Sharepoint Provider hosted add-in

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin, provider-hosted-app, mvc

I have created Provider hosted add-in with MVC, in that I have some Controllers, Models and Views.

I just want to render the Views inside the Sharepoint add-in, so that when I add that particular add-in into a SharePoint page it should render the View part

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a client Web Part, but doing the following:

"Right-click the SharePoint Add-in project (not the web application project), and then choose **Add** > **New Item** > **Office/SharePoint** > **Client Web Part** (Host Web). ("Client Web Part" is another name for "add-in part".)" 
(reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp179921.aspx)

While the example is for a ASP Forms project, it seems to work just as well for an MVC project. You can either create a new web page (view) or point to an existing one (the reference is controlled by the element.xml)
"*< Content Type="html" Src="~remoteAppUrl/ClientWebPartPage?{StandardTokens}" / >*"